# cross-domain ajax access in custom module of odoo

Tags: python, cross-domain, odoo, odoo-11

I have similar route in two controller classes in different modules,

Route1 = `ws5/mytest` is in addons/web/controllers/main->webclient class. it works fine for cross-domain only as long as it has `cors='*'` means `cors='*'` is doing the job that i need.

Route2 = `ws6/mytest` is in my custom class i.e custom_addons/mymodule/controllers/main->MyWebService. I am unable to make it working for cross-domain access

Both have 100% same code (except class name and route) that's given below, both work fine in browser, but only one `ws5` works for cross-domain access, i need `ws6` to work same

```
class MyWebService(http.Controller):

    @http.route('/ws6/mytest', cors='*', type='http', auth='none')
    def get_signature(self, **kw):
        response_content = "my 2 test"
        return response_content
```

What else I should do?

When i make any change in code it reflects in browser but access from ajax has been impossible yet for the above route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding *mymodule* to Odoo's server wide modules. 
Your server wide modules should look similar to:

- For Odoo versions 8, 9, 10: `web,web_kanban,mymodule`
- For Odoo 11: `web,mymodule`.

You can set server wide module in two ways:

- via command line arguments when starting Odoo, eg.: `$ ./odoo-bin --load=web,web_kanban,mymodule` (adapt depending on your Odoo version).
- via configuration file - add `server_wide_modules = web,web_kanban,mymodule` (adapt depending on your Odoo version) to your Odoo configuration file.

This will ensure that your module is loaded prior to selecting a database and establishing an Odoo session.

Alternatively, you may try setting your [`--db-filter`](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/setup/deploy.html#db-filter) to a specific database, eg. `$ ./odoo-bin --db-filter='^mydatabase$'`.